# Is there a perl equivalent to sed's or vim's `\l` and `\u` in substituting?

Tags: regex, perl, vim, sed, equivalent

in `sed(1)` & `vim(1)`, there are a set of 'operators' in the regex substitution syntax, `\u`, `\l`, `\U`, & `\L`. These translit characters to either lowercase, or uppercase. So if one were to type `s/(*.)/\L\1/g`, it would translit the entire string to lowercase, theoretically.

Is there equivalent functionality in Perl? Is something or eqivalent like...

```perl
while(<>) {
  s/(*.)/\L\1/g;
}
```

vaild?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all of them exist in Perl.

But your regex is invalid, I guess you want:

```
while(<>) {
  s/(.*)/\L$1/g;
}
```

If you want to lowercased the whole string, I suggest you [lc](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/lc.html):

```
while(<>) {
  $_ = lc $_;
}
```

Comment: yeah I just copypasted it to be quick. poor practice. thanks for the answer, by the way.

Comment: See [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.pl/perlrebackslash#Modifiers), but note these can be used in any interpolated string, not just regex replacements.

Comment: That regex isn't invalid. You can use `\1`, `\2`, etc in the replacement text of a substitution operator. It's not recommended and it'll trigger a warning saying "\1 better written as $1". But it works :-)

Comment: @DaveCross: I didn't say that `\1` is invalid, but the regex `(*.)` **is**.

Comment: @Toto: Oops. Yes, you're right. Sorry. Ignore me :-/